# math historian who don't belong to academia

Tags: math-history

Is there examples of math historian who don't belong to academia? Is it possible for professionally non-academician to perform good work in the field of the history of mathematics and publish? Does SCI journals entertain such works?

Edited: Does nonacademicians involve themselves in science writing specialized in mathematical sciences?

Comment: If the realm of biography is included then Constance Reid's biography of Hilbert should be included. More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constance_Reid

Comment: A truly awesome book, that!

Comment: How do you define *math historian*?

Comment: W.K. Bühler wrote a wonderful book on Gauss...